# How to simply create .gitignore file locally in Ubuntu?

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04

I can't manually create a .gitignore file using create document option.I found many ways online but they are little complicated and detour.

One way I tried is to create a .txt file and rename it into .gitignore using command line.

Is there any simple way other than that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply use the touch cmd , `touch .gitignore`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using echo command in the command line

> echo ./Hello> .gitignore

This commad will create a .gitignore file having text content "./Hello".

You can now manually erase the content from the file using text editor.